# Публикация на facebook страниц сайта wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

При публикации ссылки на стене или в группе на facebook автоматически формируются картинка, название страницы и ссылка на неё.
Пример:

[image: Пример №1 миниатюры записи]

Так работает только эта страница, для остальных страниц перепост выглядит так:

[image: Пример №2 миниатюры записи с ошибкой]

или так:

[image: Пример №3 миниатюры записи с ошибкой]

Мета теги на странице есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на первую страницу](http://argest.in.ua/kontaktyi/)

Comment: Вот то что видит скрапер:WordPress › Ошибка Your IP has been blocked!

Answer (score 0):

Для перепоста в facebook много лет использую [NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/). Работает без проблем.

Comment: Это же для автоматической публикации, а не ручной. Интересует именно ручная публикация, так как сайт контентом уже заполнен и сейчас почти не дополняется.

Comment: Там есть кнопка ручной публикации любой записи